# AWS ALB Health check fails, but host is available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I've setup a EC2 host and it's running Apache (and WordPress at the moment). It's all configured and at least locally, it's working fine.

The website is available (on port 80 for now), and is reachable both from http://localhost **AND** from my local browser at [http://{ec2-public-ip}](http://%7Bec2-public-ip%7D).

I've setup a ALB and a Target Group (containing the since EC2 instance). However, the target group is reporting the EC2 instance as "unhealthy", and the details just say "Health checks failed".

Health check settings for the TG are defaults:

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter wether I set the health-check path to "/" or some known URL (that works from my browser).

The security groups on the EC2 instance are set to allow all inbound traffic (`0.0.0.0/0`) from ports `22`, `80` and `443`. And the instance is also set to allow all outbound traffic from the EC2 instance.

All resources are in `us-west-2a`.

Result from running `curl` from my local computer (i.e. **NOT** the EC2 instance):

Using the public IP from an external host (my home computer):

```bash
# curl -I http://xx.xx.xx.xx
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 21:26:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Amazon Linux)
Link: <http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Using the PRIVATE IP address (but from the EC2 instance - it's the only EC2 instance I have):

```bash
$ curl -Iv http://172.31.21.213
*   Trying 172.31.21.213:80...
* Connected to 172.31.21.213 (172.31.21.213) port 80
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.21.213
> User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 21:47:27 GMT
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 21:47:27 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Amazon Linux)
Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Amazon Linux)
< Link: <http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.21.213 left intact
```

What I didn't expect there was that the `curl` command returned the public IP address of the instance (which I redacted above).

Added a simple text file to the Apache folder (and of course, ensured the file permissions/ownership was correctly set):

```bash
$ curl -v http://172.31.21.213/health-check.txt
*   Trying 172.31.21.213:80...
* Connected to 172.31.21.213 (172.31.21.213) port 80
> GET /health-check.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.21.213
> User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 22:03:36 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Amazon Linux)
< Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 21:57:14 GMT
< ETag: "f-60ac4cd4fb5c8"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 15
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<
I am healthy.

* Connection #0 to host 172.31.21.213 left intact
```

Comment: Please include all the Target Group's health check settings (port, path, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration will cause an HTTP request to `http://[INSTANCE_IP_ADDRESS]/`. If that request doesnt return an HTTP 200 the instance is not healthy.

Use curl or similar and inspect what happens when you hit the private IP of your server from inside the VPC (on the server, or another server in the same network). You might find your server is returning a redirect(30X) a not found(40X) or a server(50X) error for the IP even if it responds with a 200 when provided with your websites domain name.

- If you expect your instance to return some HTTP code other than 200 like a redirect normally, adjust the success codes of the healthcheck to reflect that.
- if you must check for a 200 but `/` doesnt return a HTTP 200 for whatever reason, drop a blank file in the webroot that responds to the IP address on your server and update your healthcheck path to point to that static file (or use some existing file) instead of `/`.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am able to get a 200 code both locally (`curl -I http://localhost`) or using the public IPv4 address.

Comment: The ELB will be talking to your instance on its private ip

Comment: Updated question with `curl` response using _private_ IP address.

Comment: What about the SG on the ELB itself - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html - is there a link between the ELBs SG and your instance SG for port 80 for the healthcheck?

Comment: The ALB & the EC2 instance both currently have inbound & outbound allowed on ports `80`/`443` with address `0.0.0.0/0`.

Comment: The ALB SG should have a rule where the destination is the SG id (eg sg-1234567890) of the instance SG. Any instances inside that SG should be able to receive health checks.